# SharePoint: Web config files are not identical in all servers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-config, health-analyzer

I had an error in the SharePoint Health Analyzer, where it shows: "Web Config files are not identical in the farm servers". So, I checked the web config files one by one and yes, they were not identical, so I copied the right file and now all the files are the same. But the error keeps showing, and I couldn't find the reason of the error. Is there any solution?

Thanks!